# How to create 2nd pull request from same branch when 1st pull request is not merged yet

Tags: git, request, pull

(In Github)
Say I have 2 branches named `master` and `dev`.
I work on `dev`, and submit a commit `c1`, then create a pull request `PR1` to `master`, this will fix `bug1`.
Before the `PR1` merged (sometimes my team needs lots of time to review pull requests), I continue working, fixed `bug2` so I submit a commit `c2`, then I create another pull request `PR2`. But I find this `PR2` includes 2 commits which is `c1` & `c2`. This is not my intent.

So how can I create a clean `PR2` from `dev` branch which only include `c2` commit before `PR1` is merged?

And our team has rule that one pull request should only fix one bug.

Sorry for my poor English and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using either GitHub or Bitbucket, pushing the second commit `c2` should automatically update the first pull request, so typically you would not even have the need to create a new pull request.

If, for some reason, you need the `c2` commit to go into `master` before `c1`, then this is another story.

**Edit:**

If you really want a second pull request containing just `c2` directly on top of `master`, then one approach would be to cherry-pick `c2` on top of a new branch from `master`:

```
# from master
git checkout -b new_dev
git cherry-pick c2
git push origin new_dev
```

Then, create a pull request from `new_dev` into `master`.

Comment: Thank you Tim, but how about if I really need to create a new pull request? Because `c1` commit (in `PR1`) will fix `bug1`, and `c2` commit (in `PR2`) will fix `bug2`. I wish they are in separated pull request.

Comment: I have given you an option for doing this in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Tim. This works. But could you teach me is there any method that do not change the pull request `compare` branch name (Keep name as `dev`)?

Comment: This I don't know.  Either the commit `c1` is part of the branch history, or it's not.